# Include figure with path relative to graphicspath

Tags: graphics, floats, includegraphics

I am trying to insert figures, that are deep in a folder structure. Unfortunately, I cannot directly include the directories containing each of them, since there are multiple name clashes between figure names (see below).

I was wondering, if I could include figures based on their relative path with respect to a folder I have set in the `\graphicspath`?

Here's a (non-)working MWE.
If you have a structure like

```
main.tex
├── figures
│   ├── A
│   │   └── foo.png
│   └── B
│       └── foo.png
```

I would like to be able to do `\includegraphics{A/foo}` and not `\includegraphics{figures/A/foo}`, by e.g. adding `figures` to the graphicspath. This would look like

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{figures/}
\title{Foo}
\author{Bar Baz}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\includegraphics{A/foo} ! Does not work
\includegraphics{B/foo} ! Does not work

\includegraphics{figures/A/foo} ! Works, but annoying 
\includegraphics{figures/B/foo} ! Works, but annoying

\end{document}
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Any reason why they are all called foo? If the figure names were unique, you just give all relevant paths to graphicspath and it will search them, note the syntax is `\graphicspath{{./path1/}{./path2/}...}`

Comment: And I assume the first is not working because you should have used `\graphicspath{{./figures/}}` so it has probably been eating that char by char

Comment: The issue was that I was actually using `\graphicspath{{path1/},{path2/}}` instead of `\graphicspath{{path1/}{path2}}`...

Comment: Yes, it is not super obvious that this is read as a token list and not a comma separated list.